# App Launcher Icon Disappears from screen

Tags: android, android-intent

I was trying to set the intent filters for a simple app to handle urls. I applied the basic tags for "intent-filter" like "action" ,"category".

Here I used 2 "intent-filter" tags.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MyBrowserActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter >
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
           <data android:scheme="http" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But the Launcher icon is not shown after instaling if I apply intent filters as shown below in just 1 "intent-filter" tag.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MyBrowserActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The main question here I wanted to ask is "Why the app launcher icon disappears in the second case when there is just 1 "intent-filter".

Comment: I think we can not define multiple `intent-filters` for `Activity`...

Comment: Not true: see examples at https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 18):

You need to split the  intent filter up into two. So you have

```
<INTENT FILTER>
Action category 
</INTENT FILTER>
<INTENT FILTER>
Action category data
</INTENT FILTER>
```

Comment: Why do we need to split them? Can't we add multiple "action", "category" to same intent-filter. ?
And I dont think that you need to write 1 or 2 after different intent-filter tags.

Comment: You don't. That was only to show its two intent filters and not one. No you can't combine intent filters. You can however have many intent filter in an activity. Sorry for the bad formatting. Typing from my phone.

Answer (score 2):

Split `intent-filter` into two activities:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="main"
                android:scheme="example" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: You don't need to use 2 separate activities for this. If you have two activities and one of them can be the `MAIN` action, that's fine. But if you don't and you want to designate a single activity as both intent action handler for both `MAIN` and `VIEW`, then you must do what @Orphamiel suggested in his answer. Split up the `intent-filter` into one action per `intent-filter` group under the activity.

Comment: Here's a link to read about [`intent-filter`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Receiving). And here's a direct quote from there:
`When you want to handle multiple kinds of intents, but only in specific combinations of action, data, and category type, then you need to create multiple intent filters.`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @praneetloke, is just to separate into different `<intent-filter>` groups.
I felt that it was missing an example, so here it goes. Hope it helps.

```
<activity android:name=".activities.RegisterActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter  android:autoVerify="true">
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:host="path365.page.link" android:scheme="https"/>
    <data android:host="path365.page.link" android:scheme="http"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```