# Why installed app got hidden in app drawer?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, android-manifest

I have installed an app via **Android Studio** but it got hidden due to adding **Browsable** in **manifest**.

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="myapp"
                android:scheme="returns"
                android:pathPattern="/backToApp" />
```

These are the lines i used to navigate back to app from browser. If i comment out these lines then app icon shows in app drawer.
Can somebody explains what and why it does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, `android.intent.category.BROWSABLE` is causing headaches to Android developers for a long time. Unfortunately, no one really knows the exact reason why "App Icons" dissapear. However, you could certainly solve the problem by having multiple `manifest declarations`: Please check out these links.

- [App Launcher Icon Disappears from screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21844775/app-launcher-icon-disappears-from-screen)
- [How to fix not show application icon into app drawer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53494810/how-to-fix-not-show-application-icon-into-app-drawer)
- [App icon doesn't appear after implementing deep links to my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60645136/app-icon-doesnt-appear-after-implementing-deep-links-to-my-app)

Let me know if you have any questions.

PS: I am not kidding, really, the reason behind this issue is still a [mystery](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/three-important-yet-unbeknown-android-app-launcher-behaviors-f8b6e59d5340).

Comment: Thank you. I just need to separate it in new IntentFilter.